# AngularFire2/Rxjs the right way to do "nested subscriptions" with rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire2

Working with angular and firebase on a project for my father's restaurant

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out rxjs for a bit now. I'm trying to read data in from my database to present in my view. The data consits of a category and items

```
Category
    id: str
    name: str
    desc: str
    order: num
```

```
Item
   id: str
   name: str
   desc: str
   price: str
   category: str
   order: num
```

To display the data to my view I'm trying to pull the data in, in this format

```
export interface CategoryItems {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  order: number;
  description?: string;
  items?: Array<Item>;
}
```

Where items are defined as

```
export interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: string;
  category: string;
  order: number;
}
```

The code I initially wrote contained subscriptions to get the items within the subscription to get the categories. This ended up in some not so fun bugs when I started updating the data. Going back I wrote this new code to try to fix the issue. This returned everything correctly, except the items were returned as an observable object instead of the correct format. I don't think it's even subscribing to them at all, and dont know how to map it correcly and subscribe to it all at once or sequentially.

Here's the typscript

```
this.afs.collection('categories', ref => ref.orderBy('order')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(category => {
        let tempCat: any = []
        tempCat = category.map(a => {
          let temp: any = a.payload.doc.data()
          temp.id = a.payload.doc.id

          temp.items = []
          temp.items = this.afs.collection('items', ref => ref.where('category', '==', temp.name)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(item => {
              let tempitem: any = []
              tempitem = item.map(b => {
                let temp2: any = b.payload.doc.data()
                temp2.id = b.payload.doc.id
                return temp2
              })
            })
          )
          console.log(temp)
          return temp
        })
        console.log(tempCat)
        return tempCat
      },


      )
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this.categories = result
    })
```

This what the result currently is

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {description: "test", name: "testyy", order: 0, id: "BuLw9S1NabBe86fVNvPc", items: Observable}
1: {description: "", name: "Plates", order: 1, id: "ob6W6fhjJREtpRq6QKAK", items: Observable}
2: {order: 2, name: "test3", description: "", id: "89d4HpLazuPSRBCQ2cWK", items: Observable}
3: {order: 2, name: "test4", description: "", id: "GNEcJu9gWCS67VYLYGom", items: Observable}
4: {name: "Deli Meal", description: "", order: 2, id: "L6Eq11MKjTk6RWqlSZoz", items: Observable}
```

So my question is, how do I rewrite this seciton of code to subscribe to it in the format I want, or how do I do that with a changed, better format to store it for my view?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.afs.collection('categories', ref => ref.orderBy('order')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  switchMap(
    categorys => merge(
      categories.map(category => this.afs.collection('items', ref => ref.where('category', '==', category.name)).snapshotChanges())
    )
  )
).subscribe(arrayOfResults => { // do stuff });
```